# Dynamically hide and show more text upto a certain characters Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making this script that hides the text of a div that has more than 100 characters and shows a "more" link which onclick reveals more text.

The problem is, currently onclick it reveals all of the remaining text, whereas I want it to reveal only 100 more characters and if the div contains more text then to keep the "More" link for more text until all the text of the div has been manually revealed.

In short, if a div has a text of 500 chars, I want the more link to show 5 times, once every 100 chars.

The javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 100;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "more";
    var lesstext = "less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showChar = 100;
  $(".more").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {
      var arr = [];
      var pos = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < content.length / showChar; i++) {
        arr.push(content.substr(pos, showChar));
        pos += showChar - 1;
      }
      var html = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        html += `<div class="text-${i}" style="display: none;">`;
        html += arr[i];
        html += `  - <span id="more-${i}" style="color: red">more</span> <span id="less-${i}" style="color: green; display: none">less</span>`;
        html += "</div>";
      }

      $(this).text("");
      $(this).append(html);
      $(".text-0").css("display", "block");

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        (function(index) {
          $(`#more-${index}`).on("click", function() {
            $(`.text-${index + 1}`).css("display", "block");
            $(`#more-${index}`).css("display", "none");
            $(`#less-${index}`).css("display", "inline-block");
          });
        })(i);
      }
    }
  });
});

$("*").on("click", function() {
  var arr = $("div");
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    (function(index) {
      $(`#more-${index}`).on("click", function() {
        $(`.text-${index + 1}`).css("display", "block");
        $(`#less-${index}`).css("display", "inline-block");
        $(`#more-${index}`).css("display", "none");
      });

      $(`#less-${index}`).on("click", function() {
        $(`.text-${index + 1}`).css("display", "none");
        $(`#less-${index}`).css("display", "none");
        $(`#more-${index}`).css("display", "inline-block");
        for (var j = index + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
          $(`.text-${j}`).css("display", "none");
          $(`#less-${j}`).css("display", "none");
          $(`#more-${j}`).css("display", "inline-block");
        }
      });
    })(i);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="more">
  I am making this script that hides the text of a div that has more than 100 characters and shows a "more" link which onclick reveals more text. The problem is, currently onclick it reveals all of the remaining text, whereas I want it to reveal only 100
  more characters and if the div contains more text then to keep the "More" link for more text until all the text of the div has been manually revealed. In short, if a div has a text of 500 chars, I want the more link to show 5 times, once every 100 chars.
  The javascript is:
</div>
```